# Flutter web load json file with Localizations/translation returns null while for mobile it works (Unexpected Null value)

Tags: json, flutter, localization

Localizing/translating mobile android app (flutter with the following) works, the en.json, or any defined language asset in the folder lang for example lang/en.json or lang/fr.json will be traslated without any issue. Setting on pubspec.yaml is correct.

```
late Map<String, String> _localizedStrings;
Future<bool> load() async {
    String jsonString =
        await rootBundle.loadString('lang/${locale.languageCode}.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);

    _localizedStrings = jsonMap.map((key, value) {
      return MapEntry(key, value.toString());
    });

    return true;
  }

  String? translate(String key) {
    return _localizedStrings[key];
  }
```

pubspec declaration:

```
  assets:
    - lang/
```

When translating the string from json is called as follows:

```
child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate("SKIP")!),
```

This code works PERFECTLY for mobile app. But when running on web, the following error is thrown:

*Unexpected null value.*

If I replace the Text Widget as follows:

```
child: Text("SKIP"),
```

The null error is not thrown, clearly it shows, the issue is that when loading the json with the above code on Web, it return a null while on mobile, it loads the values.
What could be the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter web uses assests exclusively, on my mobile app, I had a folder lang not under assets and it works fine with mobile app, but for web, all assets to be under assets. I moved everything back to assets folder and it worked:(had to remove the lang folder).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code you are running has a " null void space"if your code text says Jason null the try " skip"after first code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).